# how to update a state object in react?

Tags: reactjs

I define the state

```
const [newOption, setNewOption] = useState({ name: "", age: 30 });
```

then I want to update it.

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={newOption.name}
    onChange={(e) => setNewOption((prevState) => ({...prevState, name: e.target.value}))}
/>
```

but I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null when I start typing

I need to pass the event but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React uses [Synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) which are pooled. Meaning that React will reuse the event object for other events throughout your app. In order to do this, React will nullify your event object (set the values of the event object to null) once your event has handler finished executing. Since `setNewOption()` is asynchronous, your callback can run *after* React has nullified the event object. That's why you're seeing:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

as React has already nullified the event object, so `e.target` will have a value of `null`.

One solution to fix this is to use `e.persist()` which will prevent the event object from being pooled and nullified:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={newOption.name}
    onChange={(e) => {
       e.persist();
       setNewOption((prevState) => ({...prevState, name: e.target.value}))
    }}
/>
```

React 17 plans to remove this behaviour though so in future versions of React you won't have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={newOption.name}
    onChange={(e) => setNewOption({ ...newOption, name: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To update a state object in react you have to update the value and pass in the previous state as well.

An example of this would be:

```
setState(prevState => ({...prevState, name: value }))
```